# drupal_set_title not setting $title variable

Tags: 7, theming

I'm trying to use `drupal_set_title()` in my node.tpl.php but the text I'm setting the title to is only showing up in the `$head_title` (`html.tpl.php`) variable and not the $title variable. The $title variable is still set to the node's title.

This is in Drupal 7. I've used `drupal_set_title()` multiple times like this in Drupal 6 and it has worked perfectly.

Is this broken in D7?

This is how it is being used in `node--news.tpl.php`:

```
$actual_title = $title; // save for later use
drupal_set_title('News');
```

Comment: Could you please show us the code showing how you are using it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By the time you've hit node.tpl.php it's too late to set the title as `$head_title` has already been set in [template_process_html()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_process_html/7) and the `$head_title` variable has already been output.

You'll need to use [template_preprocess_node()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7) or similar to set your title as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently trying to set the title in node.tpl.php is too late in the execution order. Same goes for `template_preprocess_node()`. Instead, it can be set in `template_preprocess_page`:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars){
    if (isset($vars['node']) && $vars['node']->type == 'news'){
        drupal_set_title('News');
    }
}
```

Comment: it's poor form to reiterate the same answer Dave gave but mark yours as the accepted answer when asking a question. Please change.